# Xcode stuck in "Uploading package to the App Store" stage while uploading

Tags: ios, xcode

I have tried to upload an application to Test Flight. The app is successfully validated.

However, when distributing, Xcode is stuck in the "Uploading" stage as shown below:

> Uploading
> Uploading package to the App Store...

[image: Uploading package to the App Store...]

I have waited 2 hours and nothing has changed.

I am using Xcode 11.1. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: which ios version is use ?

Comment: It might be worth quitting XCode, making sure it's updated. As well as doing a build clean.

Comment: I am using ios 13 @Niravshekhaliya

Comment: Sometimes it is frozing. Cancel the update and try again.

Comment: @Picode I have tried it 3-4 times.But nothing changed.

Comment: Restart Xcode... :/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I faced the same problem, and first what I tried was to check my traffic. So I found a process called `java` (ironic).

The process has since been renamed to `com.apple.dt.Xcode.ITunesSoftwareService`

[image: Activity monitor]

If you will check info about this process there will be tab `Open Files and Ports` and there in the bottom of the log window, you will see `%YourApp%.ipa`. And in general if `Sent Packets` & `Sent Bytes` increasing that's mean uploading is not stuck it's just can be one of many issues such as:

- Bad connection
- Slow upload speed
- Accepting capacity of Apple servers
- Highload network
- etc.

*To open Activity Monitor: Open `Spotlight`(cmd+space or ctrl+space) -> Type `Activity Monitor` -> open tab `Network`*

**Summary:** Don't worry, and take your time :)

P.S. For increasing speed of upload you can not include `bitcode`.

P.S.S. Try also to use the `Transporter` app, sometimes it helps to speed up uploading. (https://apps.apple.com/in/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12)

Comment: Transporter is really nice - its giving me progress in percentages. At least I know what is happening! Apple really slow today (my internet is fast, so its not me its Apple).

Comment: It took 40 minutes to upload 5mb. ios app. Also i uploaded a 4.5mb. macos app in 10 seconds. Yeah i think this is something about apple servers being busy. Take your time.

Comment: in my case i checked, com.apple.dt.Xcode.ITunesSoftwareService process,  using activity--network.

Comment: Great answer. Helped reassure me after I was sitting on a 'frozen' upload screen for 45 minutes. But following your advice, it WAS still uploading, and eventually after about 65 minutes I did get to the 'successful' upload screen.

Comment: For me com.apple.dt.Xcode.ITunesSoftwareService is sending and receiving 0 bytes, stuck for 40 minutes "Uploading package to the app store" ...

Comment: Does anybody know which website we are uploading the packages to? The reason why I am asking is that at my office they have banned all external websites except a few. Due to this, we are not able to do notarization.

Comment: it took me an hour to upload and it's done, look like apple servers are really slow

Answer (score 26):

I had this same problem. Trying to upload using Application Loader once you're on Xcode 11 doesn't work.

My solution was to use [the new Transporter app](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12).

Comment: Why Apple is doing such a poor job to facilitate devs work

Comment: This app uploaded my build successfully. Thanks for info!

Comment: I can't believe that this is not marked as an answer! Perfect solution and the app is from Apple itself so there are no trust issues! Saved me a ton of time man! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 6):

Check if Apple servers are responding from this link:
https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/
Sometimes they face issues, Apple updates this page regularly.

Answer (score 6):

In my case there was nothing to worry. It just took some time (like 2 hours).
There can be many issues. Your internet upload speed can be slow at that time or an Apple server issue.
Just sit back and relax.

Comment: 2021 and it takes 2 hours to upload an app... I love mobile development

Comment: June 2022... still....

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue for over a week. In my case, I was working on other projects at the time and their uploads were going through but one particular project was always hanging, and later fails.

I later realised when Distributing the app that `Include Bitcode for iOS Content` was checked. The upload worked after I unchecked it.

[image: Uncheck "Include Bitcode for iOS Content"]

**NB:** Including bitcode(during distribution) and enabling bitcode(in the app's project and target settings), is supposed to offer some benefit with frameworks compatibility, but it slows down upload substantially, and may even cause it to fail. It also slows down the time it takes for your binary to be processed so that it's ready for submission.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of times you just need to wait. I thought something was wrong but I waited it out and eventually it went through

Comment: That's true (n_n)

Answer (score 1):

When you archive make sure you target "Generic iOS Device" – not your physical development device. This was my issue.

Answer (score 1):

- Export your app as ipa
- use Transporter app to upload your ipa file to app store

You can download the [Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12) app on the Mac App Store.

The Transporter app for macOS is a simple and easy way to upload an app to App Store Connect for distribution on the App Store. In addition to uploading your build, you can upload your metadata packages, view delivery progress (including warnings, errors, and delivery logs), as well as a history of past deliveries.

That fixed the problem for me easily

Answer (score 0):

I myself have had the same problems in the past; partial progress and then a hang for no apparent reason.

In my experience there are two secrets for reliable upload that resolve such problems.

1. Use the latest version of Xcode (not just a new-ish one) because the protocol between the client uploader and the server tend not to be very tolerant of version differences, leading to strange hangs during upload.
2. Use the Application Loader (it comes with Xcode).  When you are in Application Loader > Preferences >  Advanced there are some check boxes.  Experiment by unticking each item and then ticking just one, and then try the upload.  This trick is often needed to get through firewalls and corporate intranets, and sometimes from a regular home Internet connection.

I have no idea what those protocols actually are, by the way!  Sometimes they make the upload faster.  I suspect you hit different servers in the upload farm according to the protocol you select.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded the ipa on the company’s network some time ago. Everything went very smoothly. Generally, the upload can be completed within 5 minutes. I also encountered this problem recently. I have been stuck in the last step of uploading..., repeated many times. Stuck here, waiting for more than 6 hours has no effect

This is how I solved it, because the company's broadband uses a telecom network operator, and my mobile phone uses a mobile network operator. I share the 4G data of the mobile phone to the computer for uploading. The exciting thing is that the upload speed is very high. Fast, and the last step will never get stuck

**I have been uploading IPA using my mobile data for the past 2 months,You can try to switch to different network operators to upload, it may have good results**

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by unchecking Include Bitcode for iOS Content

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

> when Distributing the app that Include **version control was checked**
> with **stripe with swift symbol** and **upload app symbol** ...

I unchecked version control and others two remain checked and its works perfectly .
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works 100%

Use **Transporter App** to upload an app to App Store

Answer (score -1):

Steps to do:

1. Open terminal in the project directory
2. `flutter clean`
3. `flutter pub get`
4. `cd ios`
5. `pod install`
6. open XCode and clean project build
7. new archive
8. and upload

Comment: Not everyone using flutter.

Answer (score -2):

It is basically slowness in App Store Connect Upload functionality which makes it super slow. In my case, I waited around 10-12 mins and it got completed.

Try to wait for 10-12 mins or else you can try Transporter App by Apple.

Comment: Everything in this answer has already been said in other answers.

Answer (score -3):

Steps to do:
1: Check your internet
if intenet == fine
{
wait for up-to 2 hours !
}
else
{
change your connection
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).